# How to change the default style of keys for custom keyboard in android?

Tags: android, xml, keyboard, key, android-input-method

I created my own custom keyboard in android using InputMethodService class and keyboardView with rows and keys i needed and everything is right but i need to change border radius of keys.
i tried to change it using drawable file and this is failed.

How do change the color, border radius, padding and margin of keys in keyboard??

i want to do it like as that:
[image]